# Yii DropDownListRow : map boolean values to dropdown options

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii, boolean, form-submit

i have this widget below:

```
<?php 
  echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'status', array('Active','Inactive'), 
        array(
        'id'=>'status-list',
        'class'=>'span5',
        'data-placement'=>'right'        
             )                                                           
       ); 
?>
```

I use the above to create an option whether something is active or not.
But this does not submit boolean values 'true' or 'false' , rather the strings 'Active' and 'Inactive', how do i make it submit boolean values based on the choices ? **Active means true, inactive means false?** Thanks!

Comment: array('true','false') ???

Comment: yah but,. it will display "1" and "" (blank) i want it to display 'Active' and 'Inactive' while mapping true and false values to it, respectively

Comment: array('Active'=>'true','Inactive'=>'false')...and key function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dropDownListRow() function works the same CActiveForm::dropDownList()

You need to provide a key => value array.
Where key is the drop down option value that is sent to the server and value is the option display string that the user sees.

Eg for your example try

```
<?php 
  echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'status', array('true' => 'Active', 'false' => 'Inactive'), 
        array(
        'id'=>'status-list',
        'class'=>'span5',
        'data-placement'=>'right'        
             )                                                           
       ); 
?>
```

For more info see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail

Edit: 
Note that this will send the string true or false to the server, not a boolean value. So you will need to take this into account when comparing or casting the value.

Comment: Thank you.. this actually works.. however the key value pairing is :

true=>'Active' without the single quotes for the true so that the post will contain boolean.. Thanks anyway for the idea!

Comment: Note if you do it that way without quotes your array will be converted to `array(1 => 'Active', 0 => 'Inactive')` as PHP does not allow a boolean as an array key